# PayPal Encrypt cart data

Tags: encryption, paypal, expressionengine

Im using ExpressIonEngine, and there is some module Simple Commerce, which doesnt provide what I want.

Created everything that I needed, but then I wanted to improve it, so everything in cart should be encrypted, so none can alter DOM or whatever... :)

Here is example array which I'm encrypting, but when I submit form to PayPal Sandbox, Im getting error like: **We were unable to decrypt the certificate id.**

```
Array
(
    [cmd] => _cart
    [business] => info@SomeDomain.com
    [cert_id] => *********** // hidden off course
    [upload] => 1
    [return] => http://SomeDomain.com/shop/thanks/
    [cancel_return] => http://SomeDomain.com/shop/
    [lc] => EN
    [currency_code] => EUR
    [custom] => 1
    [item_number_1] => 711
    [item_name_1] => Some Issue 03
    [amount_1] => 5.90
    [quantity_1] => 3
    [item_number_2] => 708
    [item_name_2] => Some Issue 02
    [amount_2] => 1.00
    [quantity_2] => 5
)
```

Form is like:

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="encrypted" value="-----BEGIN PKCS7-----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-----END PKCS7-----">
    <input type="submit" value="Checkout With PayPal" />
    </form>
```

Tried 2 way of encrypt.

1. ExpressionEngine function encrypt_data(). This works well but only for one product and adding directly to PayPal shopping cart. When I pass data from above array to the same encrypt function, PayPal cant decrypt certificate id?!
2. Tried also function from [here](http://www.stellarwebsolutions.com/en/articles/paypal_button_encryption_php.php) but same problem... PayPal cant decrypt certificate_id.

I know that everything works, because native EE function works.
Could any one help me and suggest what to do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.scrobbld.com/paypal/protecting-your-payments-with-ewp/

Works, just exchange the certificater params.

Comment: @corneliue Amzar: Giving only link as an answer is not a good practice. In case the link get changed/removed/updated, the answer automatically become invalid. You should explain the answer and then give link as reference.